# How to give execute permissions to a drive on Steam?

Tags: 12.04, installation, steam

I even tried some answers but I am a newbie at Ubuntu. I had no idea of what was everyone talking about. So please don't consider this a duplicate. I just need an easy how-to.

Comment: Could you be a little more specific about *what* you need to do?

Comment: A little more detail on what you want to do would be helpful?  What is the error, what led you to thinking you need to give execute permissions to a drive "on" steam, and what, if anything, you tried.

Comment: give execute perms to a drive for a Steam Library.It need execute perms.The drive i need to install it has Windows XP

Comment: Rather than repeating yourself or lashing out at the people trying to help, please edit your question to explain what you're trying to accomplish. Perhaps if you explained by showing us what answers you've tried.

Comment: Please use the About and FAQ sections of this site in order to learn how to use this site in a more constructive manner.  Try using the search function and the votes filter to show better questions and answers as voted by the community.

Comment: FAQ = help or help = FAQ

Answer (score 2):

Now, you can fix it like this:

By presuming you have Ubuntu installed, I've fixed this problem by adding this line in the `/etc/fstab` file:

```
/dev/sda6 /media/MEDIA7 ntfs-3g defaults,user,locale=en_US.utf8,exec,uid=1000,gid=1000 0 0
```

Presuming that your external disk is formatted AS NTFS, replace `/dev/sda6` with your disk path (you can find it out using `fdisk -l`). The `/media/MEDIA7` is the mount point. Make sure that you replace the integer values of `uid` and `gid` with your own (you can get them by using `id`).

Now written in a different way:

1. Open terminal
2. Type `mkdir /media/MEDIA7`
3. Type `gedit /etc/fstab`
4. Copy/Paste this line:

   ```
   /dev/sdaX /media/MEDIA7 ntfs-3g defaults,user,locale=en_US.utf8,exec,uid=1000,gid=1000 0 0
   ```
5. Edit it to your info, you can get info by typing `fdisk -l` in terminal.
6. Restart.

Found here:
http://steamcommunity.com/app/221410/discussions/0/864974467574115543/?l=danish

Another workaround could be this:

1. Open terminal
2. Type `mkdir /MNT/DISKTHATISMOUNTED/MySteamLibrary`
3. Type `chmod -R 777 /MNT/DISKTHATISMOUNTED/MySteamLibrary`
4. Now create the steamlibrary through steam

Note:

- `/MNT/DISKTHATISMOUNTED` you have to edit yourself to point to where your disk drive is mounted.